# Show last 3 months from selected month in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table that contains four columns months (Format: mmm-yy), staffs, sales, expenses. I want to create three bar graphs for staff, sales, and expenses with the month in the axis for each bar graph. I want to create a month filter so that if I select a particular month data of that month and previous two months should be shown in the graph.

When I select Aug 17 in the filter than data of only Jun-17, July-17 and Aug-17 should be shown in the bar graph

[image: Graph]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best way to do this, but I can get it working as follows (I will assume your table name is `Sales`):

1. Create a separate table to use as your slicer. Modeling > New Table

---

```
SlicerTable = VALUES(Sales[MonthofYear])
```

---

2. Create a new measure that returns blank for the months you don't want.

---

```
3MonthSales = 
    VAR SelectedDate = SELECTEDVALUE(SlicerTable[MonthofYear])
    VAR CurrentDate = SELECTEDVALUE(Sales[MonthofYear])
    RETURN IF(CurrentDate <= SelectedDate &&
              CurrentDate >  EOMONTH(SelectedDate,-3),
              SUM(Sales[Sales]), BLANK())
```

---

3. Create a slicer on `SlicerTable[MonthofYear]` and a bar chart on `Sales[MonthofYear]` and `Sales[3MonthSales]` and you should get something like this:

[image: Bar Chart]

Comment: I'm trying to implement this functionality but bar chart is only showing one month - the selected one, what could i be doing wrong?

Comment: Is your slicer table a separate unrelated table like I specified?

Comment: Got it working now, it was a date format mismatch between my slicer table & the main table